# How to set column toggle default text

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to set the default text of column-toggle in jquery mobile.

This should happen through code and not in the html.

I tried this:

```
$(document)
    .ready( function() {
         $("#myTableID").prop("data-column-btn-text","asd");
     }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $(document).ready(...  use the jQM pagecreate event. Thenyou can just set the text of the button directly using its class (.ui-table-columntoggle-btn):

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {

    $(".ui-table-columntoggle-btn").text("asd");

});
```